# Ruby on Rails: link_to not having appropriate ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I got this error

```
Couldn't find MenuBar with ID=add_page_to_menu
```

But my code for the link that creates that error is as follows:

```
<%= link_to "add", 
              :controller => "admin/menu_bars", 
               :action => "add_page_to_menu", 
               :page => page.id,
               :menu => @menu_bar.id %>
```

The URL that I get the error on is

```
http://example.com/admin/menu_bars/add_page_to_menu?menu=1&page=1
```

it should look something like `example.com/admin/menu_bars/add_page_to_menu/1?menu=1&page=1`
(I think, I could be wrong, seeing as how its not working =(

the corresponding action in the controller:

```
  def add_page_to_menu
    @menu_bar = MenuBar.find(params[:menu])
    @page = LinkPage.find(params[:page])

    @menu_bar.link_pages << @page
    if @menu_bar.save
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @menu_bar.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

Routes:

```
 map.namespace "admin" do |admin|
    admin.root :controller => :site_prefs, :action => :index
    admin.resources :site_prefs
    admin.resources :link_pages
    admin.resources :menu_bars
  end
```

Comment: I think we'll need a little more information. Can you paste the controller method that's rendering this view and the snippet of routes.rb that creates these routes?

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that symbol for `:action` should be a string.

Comment: there you go. Also, as long as the action / controller doesn't have a "/" they can also be symbols. which i prefer, cause it's two less keystrokes. (unless you're using aptana, then its the same). But I changed it to quotes, just to try it. No change in error.

Comment: Could you post the relevant routes? I would guess that you have a namespace: admin.... resources :menu_bar which would define a "show" thus looking for admin/resources/menu_bar/:id where :id is add_page_to_menu

Comment: Why would you need that id since it is already being passed in as the `menu` param ?

Comment: Well, I have an error... thats my problem. Something is wrong with my link_to syntax, I think... but I have no idea, as I've made hundreds of link_to's before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route is going to eval to

`http://example.com/admin/menu_bars/:id?menu=1&page=1`

so Rails is looking for a `MenuBar` with an ID of `add_page_to_menu`. You need to add a member method to the routes for your custom action. The routes should look like this:

```
map.namespace "admin" do |admin|
  admin.root :controller => :site_prefs, :action => :index
  admin.resources :site_prefs
  admin.resources :link_pages
  admin.resources :menu_bars, :member => { :add_page_to_menu => :get }
end
```

and the `link_to` should look something like this:

`link_to("add", menu_bar_add_page_to_menu_path(@menu_bar, :page => @page.id)`

and the url produced should look something like this:

`http://example.com/admin/menu_bars/1/add_page_to_menu?page=1`

There's still some optimization to be done in that, but I think it will get you beyond this issue at least.

Comment: adding that bit to my routes, messes up all of my links. =\, And at one point I got a proxy error... which is weird.. cause I'm not using one. (the proxy error said that it couldn't handle the request GET/admin/.

Comment: Oops, had the syntax backwards on the member route. It should be `admin.resources :menu_bars, :member => { :add_page_to_menu => :get }` instead. Can you try that?

Comment: thanks, I also found an alternative. If I hardcode the :id attribute in my link_to, it stops erroring. silly rails.